# Cartthrob extload.php Fatal Parse error on checkout confirmation page

Tags: cartthrob

My extload.php keeps throwing this error on the checkout confirmation page, ee 2.11.9 & Carthrob 2.6. Any ideas why it would do this, the ParserFactory file is in the correct location. If I refresh the page the order goes through okay.

```
Fatal error: Class 'EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Library\Parser\ParserFactory' not found in /usr/www/users/dvbedgxbkf/system/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php on line 2394
```

Comment: Which payment gateway you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Updated CT to 2.71 and works now.